# Angular disordered (asynchronous) calls to webApi

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a textbox that, at every input do a call to a webapi.
The problem is that, If I write in the textbox a little bit fast, the call and the call's responses are disordered.

For Example, If I write "hello"

- call with h
- call with "hel"
- call with "hello"
- call with "hell"
- call with "he"

Every calls manage response data, so I have the last data relative to word "he" even if I wrote "hello"

Here the code

HTML

`<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="txtSearchModel" (keypress)="digitSearch($event)">`

TS

```
digitSearch($event)
{
         this.modelService.searchModel(this.txtSearchModel)
         .then(response => {
         if (response && response.Code == 200) {
            //Manage Response.Data
         }
      });
}
```

How can I do to manage Syncrhronous call or do only one call when the user stops digit?

Thanks

Comment: You just need to change event use keyup event instead of keypress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case of delaying changes of the input, please use **Angular Reactive Forms** which is best fit for this practice.

```js
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
txtSearchControl = new FormControl();
ngOnInit() { 
    this.txtSearchControl
        .valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(1000))
        .subscribe(x=> this.digitSearch(x));
}
```

```html
<input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       [formControl]="txtSearchControl">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use keyup event instead of keypress:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="txtSearchModel" (keyup)="digitSearch($event)">
```

Comment: nothing changed, the call starts when I do keyUp instead of keydown, but also in this case in a word of 5 digits, starts 5 calls asynchronously

Comment: when you want to call api service?

Comment: when the user doesn't write anything for 1 second

Comment: so for that you can use setTimeout(functioncall(), 1000);

Comment: I think best way to call digitSearch is when user Enter key press

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172479/discussion-between-parth-savadiya-and-martina).

Comment: Here is the working example https://jsbin.com/zitemil/18/edit?html,js,output
for more detail see https://medium.com/aviabird/rxjs-reducing-number-of-api-calls-to-your-server-using-debouncetime-d71c209a4613

Answer (score 0):

**Use ngModelChange with the updateon blur** instead of keypress and this will only fire event when the input has lost focus i.e. next element is focused. It will be fired once when input is finished.

```html
<input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="txtSearchModel"
    [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
    (ngModelChange)="digitSearch($event)">
```

Comment: Then remove [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}" and your events will become synchronous

Comment: Is there a way to do the call only if the user doesn't write anything for 1 second

Comment: Yes it is debounceTime(1000). But is it is applied to the observable like this : observable$.pipe(debounceTime(1000));

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should be useful to use a Typeahead component like [this](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples).

With this component you can use a `debounceTime` operator and you can also fire the call only with a min number of chars typed by user that you can configure.